# R how can I calculate difference between rows in a data frame

Tags: r, diff, dataframe

Here is a simple example of my problem:

```
> df <- data.frame(ID=1:10,Score=4*10:1)
> df
       ID Score
    1   1    40
    2   2    36
    3   3    32
    4   4    28
    5   5    24
    6   6    20
    7   7    16
    8   8    12
    9   9     8
    10 10     4
    > diff(df)

Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Can anyone tell me why this error occurs?

Comment: note that ``aPaulT`` answered your question and it would help the site if you selected it as correct by clicking on the tick mark.  Or any of the other excellent solutions, if you think that would be more helpful.

Answer (score 44):

diff wants a matrix or a vector rather than a data frame. Try

```
data.frame(diff(as.matrix(df)))
```

Comment: +1 nice - I suppose it makes sense since a matrix is just a vector with a 2nd dim attribute.

Comment: For reference, some [benchmarks](http://rpubs.com/mrdwab/bmft) on a 1000000 row by 5 column dataset.

Comment: Note that unlike the ``head/tail`` and ``nrow(df)`` solutions, this will not work on certain types of non-numeric objects, such as POSIXlt. (A ``dplyr`` solution also fails with POSIXlt objects)

Comment: Indeed benchmarks suggest ``diff(as.matrix)`` and ``data.table``  are [fastest](https://gist.github.com/ptoche/7917cfcec9391656d8bdf727f3e1d808). But I'll probably go on using ``head/tail`` or ``seq_along`` for years to come.

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
> tail(df, -1) - head(df, -1)
   ID Score
2   1    -4
3   1    -4
4   1    -4
5   1    -4
6   1    -4
7   1    -4
8   1    -4
9   1    -4
10  1    -4
```

You can subtract or add two `data.frame`s together if they are the same dimensions. So, what we are doing here is subtracting one `data.frame` that is missing the first row (`tail(df, -1)`) and one that is missing the last row (`head(df, -1)`) and subtracting them.

Comment: +1 imaginative. I would never think that `head` with -1 would return everything except the first row. Clever

Answer (score 14):

Another option using `dplyr` would be using `mutate_each` to loop through all the columns, get the difference of the column (`.`) with the `lag` of the column (`.`) and remove the NA element at the top with `na.omit()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_each(funs(. - lag(.))) %>%
    na.omit()
```

EDIT:

Instead of `mutate_each` (deprecated - as mentioned by @PatrickT) use `mutate_all`

```
df %>%
    mutate_all(funs(. - lag(.))) %>%
    na.omit()
```

---

Or with `shift` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), loop through the columns (`lapply(.SD, ..`)`) and get the difference between the column (`x`) and the`lag`(`shift`by default gives the`lag`as`type = "lag"`).  Remove the first observation i.e. NA element.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) (x- shift(x))[-1])]
```

Answer (score 12):

Because df works on  vector or matrix. You can use apply to apply the function across columns like so:

```
 apply( df , 2 , diff )
   ID Score
2   1    -4
3   1    -4
4   1    -4
5   1    -4
6   1    -4
7   1    -4
8   1    -4
9   1    -4
10  1    -4
```

It seems unlikely that you want to calculate the difference in sequential IDs, so you could choose to apply it on all columns  *except* the first like so:

```
apply( df[-1] , 2 , diff )
```

Or you could use `data.table` (not that it adds anything here I just really want to start using it!), and I am again assuming that you do not want to apply `diff` to the ID column:

```
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[ , list(ID,Score,Diff=diff(Score))  ]
    ID Score Diff
 1:  1    40   -4
 2:  2    36   -4
 3:  3    32   -4
 4:  4    28   -4
 5:  5    24   -4
 6:  6    20   -4
 7:  7    16   -4
 8:  8    12   -4
 9:  9     8   -4
10: 10     4   -4
```

And thanks to @AnandaMahto an alternative syntax that gives more flexibility to choose which columns to run it on could be:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, diff), .SDcols = 1:2]
```

Here `.SDcols = 1:2` means you want to apply the `diff` function to columns 1 and 2. If you have 20 columns and didn't want to apply it to ID you could use `.SDcols=2:20` as an example.

Comment: +1 for the edits. It will make it less confusing for future visitors to this question.

Comment: I tried this but the last row is 0. how do I do the difference from yesterday - today and put the value in today's row so that the last columns are not 0? +1

Answer (score 5):

I would like to show an alternative way for doing such kind of things even often I have the feeling it is not appreciated doing this in that way: using sql.

```
sqldf(paste("SELECT a.ID,a.Score"
            ,"      , a.Score - (SELECT b.Score"
            ,"                   FROM df b"
            ,"                   WHERE b.ID < a.ID"
            ,"                   ORDER BY b.ID DESC"
            ,"                   ) diff"
            ," FROM df a"
            )
      )
```

The code seems complicated but it is not and it has some advantage, as you can see at the results:

```
    ID Score diff
 1   1    40 <NA>
 2   2    36 -4.0
 3   3    32 -4.0
 4   4    28 -4.0
 5   5    24 -4.0
 6   6    20 -4.0
 7   7    16 -4.0
 8   8    12 -4.0
 9   9     8 -4.0
 10 10     4 -4.0
```

One advantage is that you use the original dataframe (without converting into other classes) and you get a data frame (put it in res <- ....). Another advantage is that you have still all rows. And the third advantage is that you can easily consider grouping factors. For example:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID=1:10,grp=rep(c("v","w"), each=5),Score=4*10:1)

sqldf(paste("SELECT a.ID,a.grp,a.Score"
            ,"      , a.Score - (SELECT b.Score"
            ,"                   FROM df2 b"
            ,"                   WHERE b.ID < a.ID"
            ,"                         AND a.grp = b.grp"
            ,"                   ORDER BY b.ID DESC"
            ,"                   ) diff"
     ," FROM df2 a"
     )
)


   ID grp Score diff
1   1   v    40 <NA>
2   2   v    36 -4.0
3   3   v    32 -4.0
4   4   v    28 -4.0
5   5   v    24 -4.0
6   6   w    20 <NA>
7   7   w    16 -4.0
8   8   w    12 -4.0
9   9   w     8 -4.0
10 10   w     4 -4.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding this a few years later for completeness- you can use a simple  `[.data.frame` subseting in order to achieve this too

```
df[-1, ] - df[-nrow(df), ]
#    ID Score
# 2   1    -4
# 3   1    -4
# 4   1    -4
# 5   1    -4
# 6   1    -4
# 7   1    -4
# 8   1    -4
# 9   1    -4
# 10  1    -4
```

Comment: @akrun, you had some nice stuff there.The dplyr one will bring you a lot of  upvotes in the long run- guaranteed. Please post

Comment: Okay then, though it is against my principles :-)

Comment: Even later... I am new to R and trying to avoid libraries. Everyone suggests 5 different libs for one task which could be solved with plain R. I don't get this mentality of adding dependencies to solve simple problems.

Comment: @r2p2 Well, this is the result of constant labeling R as "hard to learn" language vs dplyr/etc. as "very intuitive and easy". A big part of the R community, as it stands right now, is like a sheep blindly following the divine leader Hadley Wickham- and you can't do pretty much nothing about it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Look this answer:
[Compute difference between rows in R and setting in zero first difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416749/compute-difference-between-rows-in-r-and-setting-in-zero-first-difference)

I think that is the **easiest** way.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:8, x2=8:1, x3=11:18, x4=c(2,4,10,0,1,1,9,12))
df$vardiff <- c(0, diff(df$x4))
df
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal easy way is to use pivot_wider to create another column then you can use summarise to subtract the difference :D

It's all from dyplr package