# Applying dy/dx function over matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, gradient, apply

I am struggling with applying a gradient equation over a number of rows between two columns in a matrix. I have shown that I can calculate the gradient correctly between 2 sets of data points (y2-y1/x2-x1) by inputting the variables directly into the function. However, I cannot work out how to loop this down the matrix. For example:

```
gradient<-function(y,x){
  a<-y1-y
  b<-x1-x
  c=a/b
  return(c)
}
```

My example matrix:

```
df<-matrix(seq(1:40), ncol=2, nrow = 8)
colnames(df)<-c("x","y")


   df
     x  y
[1,] 1  9
[2,] 2 10
[3,] 3 11
[4,] 4 12
[5,] 5 13
[6,] 6 14
[7,] 7 15
[8,] 8 16
```

What I would like to do is write a function that would take y2-y1/x2-x1 and output the gradient, this would continue to y3-y2/x3-x2, and so on. Any help on this would be appreciated. I think I am going wrong with the indexing of the variables in the function.

Many thanks,
MRF

Comment: Can you show your expected output based on this input? And where does 'n' in your function come from?

Comment: Maybe look at `?diff` to calculate `y2-y1`, `y3-y2` etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R how can I calculate difference between rows in a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212097/r-how-can-i-calculate-difference-between-rows-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: Sorry I think I have got myself confused with the equation I will edit it. The expected output would be a vector containing all the gradients of y(n+1)/y(n)/x(n+1)-x(n)

Comment: @NicE I will look into diff and see if I can create a function from that. Thank you!

Comment: something like that: `diffs <- diff(df); diffs[, 1]/diffs[, 2]`.

Comment: Two remarks: 1) `df` is often used as the name for a data frame (for obvious reasons) and I find it therefore confusing that you would call your matrix `df`. 2) 1:40 creates an integer sequence. There is no need for `seq()` in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @Stibu, they have been helpful. This problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works for you. `rollapply` does the loop.

```
require(zoo)
A <- matrix(seq(1:40), ncol = 2, nrow = 8)
colnames(A) <- c("x","y")
B <- rollapply(A, width = 2, by = 1, FUN = diff)
C <- B[,"y"]/B[,"x"]
```

Comment: I have never seen rollapply before! Interesting function, I'll give it a try.

Comment: In this case, `diff` already applies to matrices; `B2 <- diff(A); all.equal(B,B2)`