# In R, how can I diff between rows of a dataframe when a column is POSIXlt?

Tags: r

I have a problem similar to this question [R how can I calculate difference between rows in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212097/r-how-can-i-calculate-difference-between-rows-in-a-data-frame); I try to apply this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/16212173/15485 with this code

```
df <- data.frame(timestamp=c("2015-02-02 09:53:44","2015-02-02 09:54:53","2015-02-02 09:55:52"),cnt=c(1,2,3))
df$timestamp <- strptime( df$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
apply( df , 2 , diff )
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

If I remove the column `timestamp` (which is of type `POSIXlt`) then it will work fine.

But... `diff(df$timestamp)` is working well:

```
Time differences in secs
[1] 69 59
```

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Do you need this as output? `c(NA, diff(df$timestamp))`

Comment: or this? `sapply(df, diff)`?

Comment: @RonakShah `c(NA, diff(df$timestamp))` is fine

Comment: @Sotos `sapply` works for me. If you write an answer I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful when using `apply` as it converts to matrix first before doing what you define it. Since it converts your object to matrix, then it is impossible to hold dates in there. Use `sapply` instead, i.e.

```
sapply(df, diff)
```